# Modern page button label displaying commands

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, button

is they anyone facing issue the modern page all the buttons seem to be in programming language :
CommandBar_NewPage instead of NewPage 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue happen in all modern pages? Or just in one page?

What does the button look like before(when did you find this issue)? Do they display normally before?

Try to open this modern page in another browser and compare the results.

It seems that somebody had edited the page. Check if somebody ever rename the label.